# how listen incoming message of single user chat and multi user chat on same listener using smack 4.1.8+

Tags: android

How to listen incoming messages for multi user chat and single user chat on same listener. now for single user chat i am using following code:

```
chatManager.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
        @Override
        public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {

    chat.addMessageListener(new ChatStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(Chat chat, ChatState state) {

            Log.d(TAG,"...stateChanged called...");

            if (ChatState.composing.equals(state)) {
                Log.d("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + " is typing..");
            } else if (ChatState.gone.equals(state)) {
                Log.d("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + " has left the conversation.");
            } else {
                Log.d("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + ": " + state.name());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {

            Log.d(TAG,"---Received a message---");
            Log.d(TAG,"participant: "+chat.getParticipant());
            Log.d(TAG,"message.getBody(): "+message.getBody());
            Log.d(TAG,"message.getFrom(): "+message.getFrom());
            Log.d(TAG,"message.getType(): "+message.getType());
            Log.d(TAG,"message.getSubject(): "+message.getSubject());

            String from=message.getFrom();
            String sender_id="";
            if(from.contains("/"))
            {
                sender_id=from.split("/")[0];
                Log.d(TAG,"The real sender_id is :" +sender_id);
            }
            else
            {
                sender_id=from;
            }

            Intent intent=new Intent(ChattingConnectionService.NEW_MESSAGE);
            intent.setPackage(mContext.getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra(ChattingConnectionService.BUNDLE_FROM_USERID,sender_id);
            intent.putExtra(ChattingConnectionService.BUNDLE_MESSAGE_BODY,message.getBody());
            mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
            Log.d(TAG,"Received message from :"+sender_id+" broadcast sent.");
        }
    });

        }
    });
```

And for multi user chat  i am using following code:

```
 multiUserChat=multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(stringExtra);
    multiUserChat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Message message) {
            Log.d(TAG,"---process message called in joinRoom method");
            Log.d(TAG,"---Received a message from: "+message.getFrom());
            Log.d(TAG,"message.getBody(): "+message.getBody());
            Log.d(TAG,"message.getFrom(): "+message.getFrom());
            Log.d(TAG,"message.getType(): "+message.getType());
            Log.d(TAG,"message.getSubject(): "+message.getSubject());

            if(message.getBody()!=null)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ChattingConnectionService.NEW_MESSAGE);
                intent.setPackage(mContext.getPackageName());
                intent.putExtra(ChattingConnectionService.BUNDLE_FROM_USERID,message.getFrom());
                intent.putExtra(ChattingConnectionService.BUNDLE_MESSAGE_BODY,message.getBody());
                mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                Log.d(TAG,"Received message from :"+message.getFrom()+" broadcast sent.");
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to listen all these incoming messages on same listener? please help me? I am on fire in office. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your infrastructure for the chat looks like, but anyhow I would recommend using the [Firebase Cloud Messaging Api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (former Google Cloud Messaging)

When user `A` is sending a message to user `B`, when the server gets this message you can use the Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a message or payload to user `B` and notify the user that he/she has received a message.

For a groupchats you can either use the solution above, when user `A` has sent a message to the groupchat `workaholics` your chat-server is querying all the recipients in that room, e.g the users `B` and `C`.

Another tip for handling a listener for a groupchat would be to use the **Topic Messaging** feature from Firebase Cloud Messaging found here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) is the way to go when you want to send notifications to specific devices or groups of devices. Works for both Android, iOS and more..